# Fastboot Kindle Fire 2

Tags: amazon-kindle

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks for all the help. I think I found it!

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2035047

**EDIT 1:**

Putting this edit on top of the post so that people read it first.

I got the device recognized as a Kindle, and am now able to flash system images onto it.
Anyone know where I can get a Kindle Fire 2 system image?

---

**EDIT 0:**

The screen suddenly lit up and I have an icon that says "Fastboot kindle fire".

I have a new device now:

> TATE-PVT-08

However, `fastboot devices` still gives me a blank line, and I still get the "waiting for device" message.

Also, my device did not "install correctly." I tried to install it looking for driver software online, but that didn't work.

And *I am* running fastboot with elevated privileges.

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I succeeded in bricking my Kindle Fire 2 last month while trying to install an Android operating system (yes, I know, I should have been more careful).

Today the fastboot cable arrived and I connected the Kindle Fire 2 to my computer. The screen is still black, but when you press the power button, a picture of a low battery with a charging sign pops up momentarily.

I tried to flash my device with fastboot (in the android tools), but I get the text:

> < waiting for device >

When I run `fastboot devices`, I get a blank line (no devices).

I'm running Windows 7, and when I looked at the device management, I couldn't find my Kindle or anything like it (might just be me, though). I unplugged the Kindle momentarily and saw no change in the device list (which usually refreshes when a device is added or removed).

Any ideas on what's going wrong and what I can do to get my device recognized by fastboot?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity here's what I did (from memory, no guarantee the exact wording of the menu options will be the same):

Make sure you have Android SDK installed and Kindle Drivers installed.

1. Open up `devmgmt.msc` (device management window)
2. Go to device TATE-PVT-08. Right-click. Click "Update Driver".
3. Click "Browse my computer for driver software"
4. Click "Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer"
5. Choose Kindle Fire 2 in the list that pops up.
6. Install ADB Composite Driver.
7. Open up CMD with administrator privileges.
8. Go to `sdk\tools` in your Android SDK.
9. Download http://fs1.d-h.st/download/00021/Pv3/KF2_SRT_10.2.3.zip (Kindle Fire 2 images).
10. Unzip the file.
11. Follow the rest of http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2035047.